ImageView in android studio
I using a ShapeableImageView of material package inside a constraint layout, and I'm setting is height and width property with the help of percent instead of a fixed size (to maintain the layout when the screen size changes). And then I have a button on the bottom right of the imageView.
But the issue is that when programatically change the uri of the imageView, it increases in size, but the edit button is fixed in size so it maintains its position.
Question: Can I maintain the size of the imageView without giving it a fixed dp size so that edit button looks the same even with or without the uri change?


.xml Code:-
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/profilePictureLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4">

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="01"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="01"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/CircularImageView"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_profile_picture" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/editProfilePictureButton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


Can you try calling requestLayout on the constraint layout after setting the image?

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/profilePictureLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="01"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="01"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/CircularImageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_profile_picture" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/editProfilePictureButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_button"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/profilePic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/profilePic"
        android:src="@drawable/edit_icon" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

To keep the size and position of your ShapeableImageView and edit button consistent when changing images, set the ImageView's scaleType to centerCrop and ensure all layout constraints are correctly configured.

i tried setting the scale type as centerCrop but it didn't work.

android:scaleType="fitCenter"
// Change to fitCenter to keep image fully within bounds
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
// Add this to maintain a square shape
